# Set Opacity directly on Control which Storyboard Animation already set

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I can setup `UserControl` Opacity property correctly, but not after bound to `Storyboard`.

```cs
UserControl MyControl;
MyControl.Opacity = 0.8;   /// This works before animation set

Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation opacity = new DoubleAnimation();
opacity.From = 1;
opacity.To = 0;
opacity.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400);
Storyboard.SetTarget(opacity, MyControl);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacity, new PropertyPath(UserControl.OpacityProperty));
sb.Children.Add(opacity);
sb.Begin();

sb.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
  MyControl.Opacity = 0.5;   /// This doesn't work anymore
}
```

How to make it works after `Storyboard` complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, it might appear that you can't change the value of a property after it has been animated.
You can try:

```
sb.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
 sb.Remove(MyControl);
  MyControl.Opacity = 0.5;
}
```

the reason is explained [How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-set-a-property-after-animating-it-with-a-storyboard)

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Why would that work to `Remove` control while I'm not append `MyControl` to `Storyboard` directly?

Comment: Nice article, `FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop` does work for me. Thank you!

Comment: `sb.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
  sb.Children.Remove(blur);
  sb.Children.Remove(opacity);
};` also works for my code